# TypeError:class "takes no arguments"

Tags: python, class

I have this code:

```
class Mat():
    def __int__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def __add__(self, other):
        result = []
        for i in range(len(self.data)):
            row = []
            for j in range(len(self.data[0])):
                row.append(self.data[i][j] + other.data[i][j])
            result.append(row)
        return Matrix(result)

    def __str__(self):
        return '\n'.join(['wt'.join(map(str, row)) for row in self.data])

m2 = Mat([[1,3,5],[4,5,6]])
```

But I get an error that says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/jjunj/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/temp.py", line 18, in <module>
    m2 = Mat([[1,3,5],[4,5,6]])
TypeError: Mat() takes no arguments
```

What is wrong, and how do I fix it?

Comment: You mean `__init__`, not `__int__`.

Comment: Look very closely where it says `def __int__(self, data):`. What do you expect this method to do?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Before posting more questions, please read [ask] and make sure you understand [how to format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) your post properly. Note well that this is an English language forum, and you are expected to **ask a question** and use complete English sentences to explain what you are asking and then ask it.